# How to share two different contents in one mail-composer?

Tags: iphone, image, email, uibutton, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have two `UIbuttons` ,when clicking these two buttons it shows the `mailcomposer`,but I need to share two diffrent contents in this mail composer,let us consider there are two buttons A and B ,when clicking A I need to share a text and when we click B need to share a image.But how is it possible to share two different content in a a same `viewController`.
My code for button A is

```
(void)displayComposerSheet {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@""];


    NSMutableString *emailBody =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,delegate.selectedIndex]];
    [emailBody appendString:@"\n Notes: "];
    [emailBody appendString:textVieww.text];
    [emailBody appendString:@"\nShared using [MyBible app]"];

    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

above code is used for "A" button,this works fine,but next i want to share

```
[emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.image,delegate.image,delegate.image]];
[emailBody appendString:@"\n image: "];
        [emailBody appendString:@"image"];
```

in my "B" button code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to append the image path instead of string image twice.

Comment: Or you can attach the image as attachment.

Comment: @Robin haii,but i dont want to attach the image in the above code,image is not the matter,let us consider another text i want to share in another button click.

Comment: How can some one click a button when mail composer is showing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to toggle A and B messages in the mail message.
When the mailcomposer is shown, its modal, and you can not change the UI.

I think the easiest would be to use 3 buttons, A for A-content, B for B-Content, "C" for A and B content in the same message.

Another solution is to create you own mailcomposer overlay, that mimics the mfmailcomposer ui , where you add the 2 buttons, as toggles i presume, and then pass the result.

Comment: but how to write condition for A for A-content and B for b-content?

Comment: Ah, you would like to use the same method and differentiate on the button used ( ie different usuage using same method depending on pressing A or B button (or C )) ?
If so pass the id of the button to the method and set diff tags values on the button and use the condition on that.